# BigQuery struct as UDF return: hello world-caliber question

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to use a struct as the return type from a UDF, then extract individual fields from the results. Here is my attempt at a hello world version of the use case:

```
create temp function udf_struct_test(orig string)
returns struct<original int64, plus1 int64>
language js as """

var original = parseInt(orig);
var plus1 = 1 + original;
return { original, plus1 };

""";

with t as ( select udf_struct_test(cast (input as string)) from unnest([1,2,3,4,5]) input )
select t.original, t.plus1 from t ;
```

the result:

```
Error: Name original not found inside t at [10:10]
```

but, when I change the selection to "select * from t", I get:

```
Row f0_.original    f0_.plus1    
1   1   2    
2   2   3    
3   3   4    
4   4   5    
5   5   6
```

I've spent an embarrassingly long time trying to get this to work, and I assume I am missing something very small/stupid...right?

Answer (score 2):

Update: yep, it's something every bit as tiny/dumb as I thought.

I was trying to deference the row source, when I really wanted to dereference a column within the row source. So, all that's required to get this working is to alias the result of the UDF within the subquery. I.e. (note the "v" aliases):

```
with t as ( select udf_struct_test(cast(input as string)) v from unnest([1,2,3,4,5]) input )
select v.original, v.plus1 from t ;
```

derp.

Anyone who is opinionated about stackoverflow meta stuff, please feel free to delete this whole post if you don't think it provides any value.

Comment: I wouldn't delete the question and answer - since someone might find the same error message and your solution useful. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate version of your solution that projects the fields of the struct returned by the UDF as columns:

```
with t as (
  select as value udf_struct_test(cast(input as string))
  from unnest([1,2,3,4,5]) input
)
select original, plus1
from t ;
```

Or use `.*` on the returned struct:

```
with t as (
  select udf_struct_test(cast(input as string)).*
  from unnest([1,2,3,4,5]) input
)
select original, plus1
from t ;
```